# Windows 2008 R2 : Admin Account Expired

Tags: windows-server-2003

A Quick Question : One of our Production machine admin account has been expired. Do we need to reset its password after we enable this account?

Answer (score 0):

You'll be prompted to change an expired password next time you log in with the account.

If it's the default Administrator account and it's currently disabled, just leave it disabled - (if you must use local admin accounts) you should be using a local admin account that's been renamed, to make it harder for an attacker to guess or brute force their way into admin access on your machine.

Comment: "you should be using a local admin account that's been renamed" - I've never seen this before. Surely that's the definition of security through obscurity?

Comment: @Dan If you define that phrase broadly enough, maybe. But in that instance, aren't passwords the definition of "security through obscurity" as well? Every script kiddie and lame script in the world is going to try to guess the "Administrator" password, which won't do them any good if you rename it to Kwijybo, or what have you.

Comment: @Dan, renaming the local Administrator (and even the domain Administrator) account has been standard practice (and I believe is MS best practice) for a very long time.

Comment: To be fair, while it's been standard practice since longer than I've been in the industry, the only official mention of being an MS best practice I could find is a fairly recent Technet article about the SBS product line.